# Slickgrid can be restored after autosizeColumns()?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

In the slickgrid example4, there is checkbox option 'force fit columns' in column picker. When I check the option, the grid will call autosizeColumns method to make columns wider to fit the grid canvas width. But when I uncheck the option, it can not be restored to the initial view state. 
please could someone make any suggestion? thanks.

please view the example page.
http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

Answer (score 0):

You should play around with the `minWidth` and the `maxWidth` properties when using the `force fit column` so that you don't fall off, they should all be use in combination...
Please take a look at 2 of my previous answers I gave to similar questions, that should help you out, hope it does help.

[Slickgrid column width should automatically get resized according to widest row content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200574/slickgrid-column-width-should-automatically-get-resized-according-to-widest-row/15205550#15205550)

[Slickgrid: Final column auto size to use all remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360367/slickgrid-final-column-auto-size-to-use-all-remaining-space/17374444#17374444)

Comment: hi, there is a reply from slickgrid author. https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/706

It need to persist the initial width for each column.