# SlickGrid - Bizarre: After custom filter and viewport resize, cells gain spacing out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slickgrid

This bizarre behavior is confusing me, and I just want to know if anybody has run into this issue yet.  I'm fairly certain it's a bug with the library (which, btw, thank you for SlickGrid mleibman!).

I'm using a dataView grid with several filter options that work like this:

Binding:

```
$("#searchField").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
        this.value = "";
    }

    searchString = $.trim(this.value.toLowerCase()).split(' ');
    currFilters.searchString = searchString;

    dataView.setFilterArgs(currFilters);
    dataView.refresh();
    dataView.setFilter(searchFilter);
});

$("#fromDate").keyup(function (k) {
    if (k.which == 27) {
        this.value = "";
    }

    fromDateString = this.value;
    currFilters.fromDateString = '01/01/1969';

    dataView.setFilterArgs(currFilters);
    dataView.refresh();
    dataView.setFilter(searchFilter);
});
```

...etc, etc, etc.

Filter:

```
function searchFilter(item, args) {
        for (property in args) {
            if (args.hasOwnProperty(property) && property == "searchString") {
                if (args[property] != "" && item["ClientName"].toLowerCase().indexOf(args[property]) == -1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (args.hasOwnProperty(property) && property == "fromDateString") {
                var _d = new Date(parseInt(item["RecordCreated"].substr(6)));
                var _f = new Date(args[property]);

                if (_f.getTime() > _d.getTime()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // etc, etc, etc...
       }
    return true;
}
```

I also have an "advanced filter" option that extends the filter toolbar above my grid to show some additional options from the default viewable.

Which has this effect on the grid/viewport:

```
$("#btnFilter").toggle(function () {
        $("#filters").stop().animate({
            height: "55px"
        }, 100);
        $("#myGrid .slick-viewport").stop().animate({
            height: "-=23"
        }, 100);
        $("#myGrid").stop().animate({
            height: "-=23"
        }, 100);
    }, function () {
        $("#filters").stop().animate({
            height: "32px"
        }, 100);
        $("#myGrid .slick-viewport").stop().animate({
            height: "+=23"
        }, 100);
        $("#myGrid").stop().animate({
            height: "+=23"
        }, 100);
    });
```

Now everything works fine.  The problem is very specific to a resulting combination of the two aforementioned parts of my application.

If I have a combination (or single) filter that returns a number of rows which do not require a vertical scrollbar and I THEN hit my "advanced filter" button, which subsequently resizes the grid and viewport manually, the individual cells have about 8px "whitespace" as if they were all shifted using left: 8px (it's about the size of the vertical scrollbar...which appears after hitting the advanced filter button even if the records dont require it...this I may be able to tweak).

Here's an image of a part of the affected grid:

[image: spacing]

I thought an easy solution would be to force the viewport to always show a vertical scrollbar but that actually didn't work.  Any thoughts or advice would be awesome!

### UPDATE

---

So I have created a work around, the issue is the viewport manual resize requiring the display of the vertical scroll bar.  The fix is good enough for me, but I'd still like to get to the bottom of the issue and/or get it confirmed as a bug so as to submit it for a resolution to Leibman.

As per request, here are my config options:

```
var options = {
        editable: false,
        enableAddRow: false,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        selectedCellCssClass: "selected",
        syncColumnCellResize: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: false,
        forceFitColumns: true,
        autoEdit: false,
        multiColumnSort: true
    };
```

Comment: Can you put this in JSFiddle?

Comment: I don't really think a fiddle is necessary

Comment: You should display your SlickGrid configuration though... are you in auto-resize mode?

Comment: @ghiscoding yes I do have forcefitcolumns enabled, options posted...I also do call grid.resizeCanvas() but only on document resize (which does not need to occur for this issue to present itself).

Answer (score 0):

You should play around with the minWidth and the maxWidth properties when using the force fit column so that you don't fall off, they should all be use in combination... Please take a look at 2 of my previous answers I gave to similar questions, that should help you out, hope it does help.

[Slickgrid column width should automatically get resized according to widest row content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200574/slickgrid-column-width-should-automatically-get-resized-according-to-widest-row/15205550#15205550)

[Slickgrid: Final column auto size to use all remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360367/slickgrid-final-column-auto-size-to-use-all-remaining-space/17374444#17374444)

Hopefully that helps you out, I know that the auto-resizing columns inside the SlickGrid is a little tricky, though I had more success using all properties of column size: width, minWidth, maxWidth...The 2nd link shows you how I made my canvas auto-resize

Comment: Resizing the grid isn't my issue =/

Comment: didn't you say that your column gets out of size and out of the grid?

Comment: the image is very small from my point of view... anyway, is that a problem with a browser in particular (pointing towards IE), I had some kind of problems similar to that with Bootstrap and IE7-8. In fact you don't seem to be using jQuery UI there, so it's most probably a CSS trick