# SlickGrid Col resize issue

Tags: slickgrid

I'm trying to find a quick fix here, when i resize SlickGrid column, the header row is few pixel off with respect to the body of the grid.  I tried `syncColumnCellResize: true,` but still couldn't solve the issue, any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

1. Before Resize, columns align perfectly
   [image]
2. After resize, please note header row is few pixel off
   [image]

3.Grid Options (i'm using ColumnPicker plugin)

```
  var options = {
    editable: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: true,
    showHeaderRow: true,
    headerRowHeight: 30,
    explicitInitialization: true,
    enableTextSelectionOnCells: true,
    syncColumnCellResize: true,
    autoEdit: false
};
```

Comment: you need to post your code, or at least some of your grid options...just displaying an image is not enough to help you out

Comment: Grid options included, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with misalignment and only seem to resolve it by using the `forceFitColumns: true` and setting the 3 properties of `minWidth`, `width`, `maxWidth`... You can also check these questions which I also provided answers, it might as well help you out:
[Slickgrid: Final column auto size to use all remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360367/slickgrid-final-column-auto-size-to-use-all-remaining-space/17374444#17374444)
[Slickgrid column width should automatically get resized according to widest row content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200574/slickgrid-column-width-should-automatically-get-resized-according-to-widest-row/15205550#15205550)

Comment: Thank you @ghiscoding, will try and keep you posted.

Comment: Then try to show a bit more of your code and/or a jsfiddle, because with just your displayed options, there's not much to see...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap or some other css lib. you can try add the following css to your code .

```
/* compatible with both IE and Chrome */
.slick-header-columns * {
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```