# How to make columns in Slickgrid cover entire grid/row width?

Tags: css, slickgrid

Im trying to get slickgrid to autoadjust the columnsizes to fit the width of the grid but it do not seem to work. There is a grayish area to the right.

This is how it looks:

[image]

When i manualy click "Adjust column-sizes" in the menu the result looks like this:

[image]

That how I want it by default and not by having to click the menu-option.

Anyone who have had the same problem and know what the fix is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is already a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794656/how-do-i-autosize-the-column-in-slickgrid you should use the forceFitColumns option

Comment: v1vendi - I have tried the tips from that thread, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the sum of column percentages to be equal to 100 to get them to display so